# Understanding Docker in Production

Tags: docker

I've been learning how to use Docker to setup dev environments, however, I'm
curious how these ideas translate to a production stack. As an example, I have a Laravel (Php) app, which uses MySQL, Redis, and Nginx

So in production, let's say I would normally have 2 application ec2 instances behind a load balancer on AWS. When setting up a similar production situation using Docker...

1) because I'd be using RDS and Elasticache, there would be no need for containers for those. So basically, id only need containers for PHP-Fpm and Nginx?

2) to have high availability, I would still have 2 (or least more than 1) ec2 instances behind the ELB.  So I suppose each instance would run the above containers (PHP and Nginx). But that sounds no different than my previous VM setup, where each server runs what it needs to serve the application.  Is that accurate?

3) with VMs, I would traditionally bake the code into an AMI and add those AMIs to a Launch Configuration and an Auto Scaling group, and that group would spin up instances as needed.  So for deployment, I would tear down the old ec2 instances and spin up new ones.  With Docker, Since these containers would be running on ec2 instances, wouldn't i still have to spin up / tear down the VMs, or would I just replace the containers and keep the VMs running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its reasonable to keep RDS, Elasticache and other fully managed services, outside of docker environment. Yes for high availability you need multiple EC2 instances having docker daemon running.

The real advantage is not coming with having two EC2 instances running two web server docker containers on each of them. Real advantages comes when you break down your application to microservices, where multiple containers in combination construct your web application providing the [benefits of microservices](https://dzone.com/articles/benefits-amp-examples-of-microservices-architectur).

Apart from that the DevOps flow would be different compared to traditional web application deployment in EC2 with autoscaling and load balancing and have many [benefits](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/7.0_Release_Notes/sect-Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-7.0_Release_Notes-Linux_Containers_with_Docker_Format-Advantages_of_Using_Docker.html). For example your source code will contain the container code as well, which will guarantee, the environment will work uniformly in your staging and production. Also you will be having images pointing to branches/tags in your source control, which allows to get new updates(delta downloads) for new releases.

If you are going to setup docker in AWS, its recommended to go with [AWS ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) to reduce management overhead.

Comment: thanks for the info.  So potentially, as it stands, since my application is just a basic API and there might not be a place for micorservices yet, I may not really benefit from Docker?

Comment: Yes if its a simple API, you can keep it for the moment. When its getting complex, you can start dockerizing the application and then slowly chunk by chuck device to microservices.

Answer (score 2):

1. You're right, you will only need to run your code in a container and it will simply access the remote services. The only thing you'll have to consider is to ensure connectivity to them.
2. You're right again, you'll need to have everything you previously had in your VMs in the Docker container so that your code works as before. Anyway, with Docker containers it is possible to run multiple instances of your app on the same EC2 instance. Of course, your app will try to run on the same port, so some extra networking layer is needed for managing ports is necessary, but it's possible. All the EC2 instances needs to have is docker installed.
3. Instead of creating AMIs and closing and spinning up EC2 instances, you'll only have to pull the new Docker image and restart the container with the new image. This means just a few seconds compared to minutes in the EC2 instances flow. This is means you have a really quick way of reverting buggy deploys and opens the doors for a setup in which 0% downtime can be reached.

Comment: thanks for the info.  So it seems that for now, because my  application doesn't require much in the way of containers, I may only benefit from the fast deployments -- at least until I require more by way of containers

Comment: IMO the biggest advantage is the fast deployments. It depends very much on how often you deploy to production and how important is for you to have close to 100% uptime. If you have rare deployments you might not benefit so much from migrating to Docker.

Comment: "Fast deployments" in Docker really depends on other factors and what you consider the "deployment". In reality, Docker actually adds some steps to the process that people generally should be including in their end to end deployment time. There is building the Docker image (which is generally an addition to your current build process and will add some time), pushing the image to a registry (the image needs to be available for the servers to pull), and then pulling the image on all servers. At the end of the day, Docker may _not_ be any faster than your current method. Food for thought.

Comment: Of course, deployment speed is a longer discussion. Those steps need to be done in a way or another anyway. The OP is building AMIs and closing/opening EC2 instances at deployments. This is arguably slower than building the image and pulling it. There is of course some work to be put into migrating towards Docker (managing the registry, dockerfiles, etc.), that's why I said it depends on the use case.

Comment: Those are interesting points. Though as it stands, we are doing continuous deployment using Jenkins and pushing to production up to 5 times a day. And each of those deployments take maybe 10 or so mins, from AMI building, to Terraform spinups